# 1292 Incorrect datetime value for column 'updated_at'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6.2

I've created a table in Laravel with standard datetime columns:

```
Schema::create('lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('ref');
    $table->string('provider');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->unique(['provider', 'ref']);
});
```

When I try to do a simple record creation with Eloquent:

```
List::updateOrCreate([
    'provider' => 'test',
    'ref'      => 'S4d3g'
], [
    'name' => 'Plan'
]);
```

I am given this message (which is a raw console output, so ignore the lack of quotes):

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-08 02:25:07' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `lists` (`provider`, `ref`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, S4d3g, Plan, 2020-03-08 02:25:07, 2020-03-08 02:25:07))
```

Running the query manually on the database as raw SQL also doesn't work:

```
insert into `lists` (`provider`, `ref`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('test', 'S4d3g', 'Plan', '2020-03-08 02:25:07', '2020-03-08 02:25:07')
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Inexplicably, if I change the date to anything other than 2 AM, it works:

```
insert into `lists` (`provider`, `ref`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('test', 'S4d3g', 'Plan', '2020-03-08 01:25:07', '2020-03-08 01:25:07')
insert into `lists` (`provider`, `ref`, `name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('test', 'S4d3g', 'Plan', '2020-03-08 03:25:07', '2020-03-08 03:25:07')
```

What could be causing this bizarre MySQL level dislike of 2 AM on the timestamp?

Comment: This is not a reproducible problem, and there is nothing at all special about 2 AM to MySQL.

Comment: I would love to believe that. I've never seen this happen before in my life but I can watch it happening. I could even record a screenshare running the SQL raw to demonstrate.

Comment: Just a hunch: In your country, does daylight saving time start today maybe, and clocks go from 1:59am to 3:00am? This could explain the error, since 2am simply _wouldn't exist_ on that day.

Comment: @CherryDT That is only way I could explain this without assuming I'm in an episode of the Twilight Zone. Daylight Savings is (also nonsensically) upon us.

Comment: This is an annoying consequence of using `DATETIME` which uses local timezone. (I prefer `TIMESTAMP` for that reason.) Also, think about what happens when DST ends - there are _two_ 2am-s, but in SQL you cannot distinguish between 2A:00 and 2B:00, so be ready for that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you are in the US, in a timezone where [daylight saving time just started](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa).

Therefore, 2am *does not exist* today.

> March 8th, 2020 - Daylight Saving Time Starts
>
> When local standard time is about to reach
>   Sunday, March 8th, 2020, 02:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
>   Sunday, March 8th, 2020, 03:00:00 local daylight time instead.
>
> Sunrise and sunset will be about 1 hour later on March 8th, 2020 than the day before.
>   There will be more light in the evening.

`DATETIME` in MySQL uses a local time (the timezone can be set in a multitude of ways) and in your case it's probably *your* local time, which is why you run into this issue. If you actually meant *UTC*, you'd have to set the timezone to UTC first using `SET time_zone = "+00:00"` or by setting the correct [global configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/1871033).

Since your PHP library is generating this (invalid) time, I assume you have a mismatch between the timezones used by PHP and by MySQL.